# Unpackage a JObject/JArray to check if it contains a specific field

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, json.net

I want to unpackage a JObject to see if it contains the field "categories". The JObject is this (with some irrelevant data inside categories.

```
{{
  "categories": [
  ]
}}
```

My attempt (naming the JObject containing categories `jobj`):

```
var x = jobj.Value<double?>("categories");
```

I get this exception:

```
{System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Convert[T,U](T token)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Value[T](Object key)
   at xxx.JsonSchemaValidator.validateAgainstJsonSchema(JObject list, String schemaFilePath)}
```

It's a bit weird it calls it a JArray but I'm fine with it being a JArray, just don't understand why because this is the full context of how it is used:

```
public static bool validateAgainstJsonSchema(JObject jobj, string schemaFilePath)
{
    JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(schemaFilePath));
    var x = jobj.Value<double?>("categories");

    IList<string> messages;
    bool valid = jobj.IsValid(schema, out messages);
    if (!valid)
        throw new DataMisalignedException("Failed JSON schema validation: " + string.Join("\n", messages));
    return valid;
}
```

The `validateAgainstJsonSchema` method is called like this:

```
JsonSchemaValidator.validateAgainstJsonSchema(parsedObject as JObject, "./JsonSchema/category-schema.json");
```

How do I access the data inside `jobj` to check if it has categories field?

Comment: `{{
  "categories": [
  ]
}}` is not valid JSON.  Upload it to http://jsonlint.com/ and you will get an error `Error: Parse error on line 1: Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '{'`.

Comment: @dbc Given that, how do I check if it has the categories field? The code runs without failing, just not when I try to check if it has categories so it's not about invalid data, it's about checking the data for a field. The code to handle the invalid jason is already in place

Comment: Your JSON doesn't parse.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/GDJBJg.  But if you just want to see if an `JObject` has a property named `"categories"`, just use the [indexer](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm): `var categories = jobj["categories"]; if (categories != null) { } else { }`